# Does exception sub class has to be outside class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to raise an exception for invalid argument from my class.

```
class MyFunc(object):
    class InvalidArgument(ValueError):
         pass
```

So I have sub classed from ValueError. It make more sense to put this inside class, as I don`t want my exception class to collide with other exceptions from library or other module. However inner classes are sometime discouraged in python. Where should I put InvalidArgument inside my class or outside class.

Comment: It doesn't really make much difference, other than whether you have to refer to it as `InvalidArgument` or `MyFunc.InvalidArgument`. Usually, custom exceptions are just defined at the module level for simplicity; there's usually no compelling reason to namespace them further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does exception sub class has to be outside class?

No.  But you *should* put it outside the class, at the module level scope.

> I don`t want my exception class to collide with other exceptions from library or other module.

It won't.  It will be namespaced by the module name.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, this is a matter of opinion, because Python itself does not require or prohibit the definition of an exception inside another class.

However, the only time I might define it inside the class is if the exception is *purely* an implementation detail, and it will never be raised or caught outside of one of the class's methods. Otherwise, it is just as much a feature of the *module* as the class itself, because arbitrary code may need to catch the exception (even if it is never raised by anything except a class method), and should therefore be defined at the module level.